Not controlled TextField reset input ref on each rerender
I want to use not controlled TextField with default value.
Then let user edit and check input on each entered character.
If validation fails I'm trying to set error flag but useState rerenders whole component that causes reset user's input to default value
 import { TextField } from '@mui/material';

  const emailAddressInputRef = useRef();
  const [emailError, setEmailError] = useState(false);


  const checkEmail = emailToCheck => {
    if (emailHasError(emailToCheck.trim())) {
      setEmailError(true);
    } else  {
      setEmailError(false);
    }
  };

           

 <TextField
     autoFocus
     label="Email address"
     variant="outlined"
     fullWidth
     error={emailError === true}
     inputRef={emailAddressInputRef}
     defaultValue='test@email.com'
     onKeyUp={e => checkEmail(e.target.value)}
     onBlur={e => checkEmail(e.target.value)}
 />


Please use value props instead of defaultvalue in the textField.


regardless of what I use either value or defaultValue when useState updates the state it rerenders the page that causes resetting data to default value.. I want to continue typing at current cursor position but show the error
